# Can I create links between tables in different xsd files?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xsd

I have (inherited) a .Net solution containing an xsd file with over 50 tables in it, and a large number of relationships between the tables. This is very difficult to manage, and beginning to cause performance issues (and I'm sure I'll need to add more tables at some point in the future). I'd like to break this xsd apart into logical pieces, but there are several core tables that pretty much everything is linked to in some way.

Is it possible, in Visual Studio, to create relationships between tables in different xsd files?

If so, how do I do it?

If not, what is the best alternative (I don't like the idea of duplicating these code tables across separate xsd files, but I don't really want to re-write the whole way the application interacts with the database)?

Apologies if this question is slightly vague, but there isn't any code to post, and I can't sanitize pictures if I wanted to post any.

Thanks in advance

Duncan

Comment: Perhaps you could make a sanitized 15-line version of the XSD to illustrate what you mean by "an xsd file with ... tables in it" and "relationships between the tables"?  Since *table* is not a technical term in the XSD spec, it appears you are indulging in a metaphor.  This is perfectly legitimate, if your readers understand what you are getting at (but I for one don't).  If the maintenance problems result from the size of the schema, splitting the definitions across multiple schema documents won't help; if they result from the size of this one document, splitting may help.

Comment: If you right click in an xsd then you can add: TableAdapter, DataTable, Query, or Relation. My file has a lot of DataTables (populated by specifying a SQL Server stored procedure), with Relations that link them together via foreign keys.

Comment: Ah.  Sorry for the confusion. I thought you were asking a general question about XSD, but details of the user interface in Visual Studio are outside my ken.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it is not possible to achieve what you want. An XSD file defines a DataSet; I associate a DataSet with a database, and there are no declarative means to maintain referential integrity between database objects across databases.